# Running a batch file which requires inputs directly from folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which requires 4 command line inputs. When I execute the batch file on the command prompt, it displays help message asking to input 4 values.

When I run this file directly from the folder, it opens cmd and closes immediately.

Is it possible to modify the batch file, so that when I run from folder it will open the cmd and then display the help message.?

Following is a mini version of my problem with 1 command input. The script is for a License file generation

```
@ECHO OFF
GOTO :continue

:continue
SETLOCAL
IF "%1" == "" GOTO :Help

::Set the Command Line Options
SET ARVERSION=%1

::Create Directory
SET OUT_PATH=%cd%

ECHO  Initiating Generation...

if not exist %OUT_PATH% mkdir %OUT_PATH%

::Create License File - Calling 'Subs' will create the output with actual Version
Subs ARVERSION %ARVERSION% Input.txt 1>%OUT_PATH%\License.txt

ECHO Scripts are created @ %OUT_PATH%
ECHO  Generation Completed...

GOTO :End

:Help
ECHO  Starting License File Generation...
ECHO Usage:
ECHO InstallerScriptGen.bat AR_VERSION
ECHO AR_VERSION            - Version (3.2 or 4.0 or 4.2)
ECHO Example : InstallerScriptGen.bat 3.2.2
ECHO Please Note that input of incorrect values will result in wrong generation.

:End
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: see `timeout /?`

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ Please find the updated minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

"Running directly from the folder" (by which I assume you mean "clicking on the icon from within Windows Explorer") causes Windows Explorer to execute the equivalent of `CMD /C <<batchfilename>>`. When invoked with `/C`, `CMD` exits (and the CMD window closes) as soon as the batch file ends. You can force the window to stay open long enough to read the output by ending the script with either the `PAUSE` command (which will cause it to wait for the user to press any key), or the `TIMEOUT` command (which will wait the indicated number of seconds before continuing, without a keypress).  See SS64's help for the [`PAUSE`](http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html) and [`TIMEOUT`](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) commands for more information.